# Are druids, rangers and elves opposed to the more "civilized" people?

Tags: forgotten-realms

The Forgotten Realms has nature oriented races and classes - like Elves from the High Forest, Druids and Rangers. How would these races and classes act if someone enters their woods and ritual places? What is they opinion on "regular" humans?

Faerun isn't that industrialized so there isn't a huge tension between the "people of nature" vs the people of the cities, so I'm guessing they won't kill tresspassing humans on sight, like the elves in The Witcher would. But I also can't believe they'd just go "Nah, let them be, whatever" and let them in.

I'm playing in an RP Neverwinter Nights 2 server (based on D&D 3.5 rules in the Forgotten Realms). I'm a Wood Elf and all action is in Cormanthor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just like in the real world, this varies a lot. Every community of "nature" types is different and can't be put neatly into one of two buckets labelled "will react with violence" and "won't react with violence." Even within one of the categories you called out, it varies because every person, and every community made up of people, have different goals and priorities which can make *other* groups count as friend or enemy to them.

Just like an unannounced visit to a friendly human realm will likely be met with friendly greetings but a visit by outsiders to a hostile human realm might be met with extreme violence, what happens when you visit a "nature" realm is no different and will depend on what *they* think of *you*. This can be broadly generalised by species and class, but broad generalisations are never 100% true of each and every individual or community.

## A few examples of variations

Elves are a nice example, because their cultures (plural!) have been detailed quite a lot in *Elves of Evermeet* (1994). The title is poetic — it's not actually just about the elves *on* Evermeet, but rather deals with all species of elves who are welcome there (hence, excluding drow). It would be well worth tracking down in the second-hand market if you want an good reference for roleplaying inspiration.

There are elves who are xenophobic, and might react with varying levels of violence to intruders. **Green elves** are more likely to be xenophobic than other subraces of elf — they are more isolated by choice, and often (not always) react violently to intrusions on their domain — even by other elves! Even by *green* elves of enemy tribes! (But not to other green elves of friendly tribes. It varies, remember.) Other communities of green elves are not so xenophobic.

**Silver elves** are the most cosmopolitan and least likely to react with violence to intrusions on their domain — but again it varies. If you try to sail to Evermeet without an invitation, you ship will be sunk, no questions asked.

**Gold elves** are the "upper class" subrace of elf, and are more likely to distrust or dislike outsiders, but having a highly structured civilisation they're going to be civilised in how they deal with intruders. They might react well, and invite the visitors to feast with them (out of friendship, or just to be amused by the "quaint lesser creatures"). A "bad" reaction from gold elves defending their territory is more likely to be something like questioning at spear-point, or capture and interrogation, than immediate violence. Unless of course, the visitors are violent!

**Aquatic elves** generally distrust surface dwellers and will usually treat intruders as hostiles, but this isn't universally true either — the aquatic elves of the bay in Waterdeep have a friendly working relationship with the rulers of the city and safeguard the harbour from *political* enemies or evil aquatic races.

Again, these are *only* examples and broad generalisations. Individual communities will be different, based on who they consider their friends and enemies. Even a single community's reactions can change, too, based on individual elves' feelings and changes in their internal politics.

Continuing the theme, rangers and druids are going to be very individual in their responses. What are the intruders doing when they're spotted? Do their actions reveal themselves as a danger to the wilderness, to the ranger's plans, or the druidic circle's interests? Have there been recent problems with other intruders who are similar to the current intruders? Each ranger, each druid, each community is going to react based on whether they see the intruders as a threat to their plans, goals, and values, or as an opportunity to further those same plans, goals, and values.

## Cormanthor specifically

The situation in [Cormanthor](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Cormanthor) depends on the year, and how your DM is handling the [Retreat](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Retreat). If they're handling the Retreat in a way that's customised in any way, then you just have to ask them for details. Otherwise, I can make some generalisations based on the canon timeline.

If the game is set after DR 1374, when the Retreat was pretty much complete, then Cormanthor is pretty much empty of organised elven communities. How individual elves who have stayed behind feel about intruders into Cormanthor (or specific parts of Cormanthor, since it's really many different forests) will be very much a personal matter, and might be intimately tied (or not) to their life leading up to and during the Retreat years and their reasons for not embarking on it themselves.

If the game is set before DR 1344 (the year the Retreat was announced), then the situation in Cormanthor is much like anywhere else, except for the matter of Myth Drannor's ruins being "off limits" to outsiders. (That's assuming that you're not playing in *ancient* history, when Myth Drannor was the capital of the multi-ethnic empire of Cormanthyr.)

If the game is set in Cormanthor between DR 1344 and DR 1374, then your DM has a very special campaign in mind! Expect the politics of elven seclusion and the exclusion of non-elves from Cormanthor to be significant issues, with individual and community opinions all over the spectrum. This is very much in the "ask your DM" realm.

Comment: Well thanks, explained a lot;] and I forgot to tell except the basic rp informations, well I'm a Wood Elf and all action is in Cormanthor, was just curious about some things but this post helped me a lot;]

Answer (score 2):

It would be entirely up to the individual settlement, I expect, and even the individual person. There is not a generic, stereotypical stance for all nature-dwellers to be eco-warriors.

However, there is certainly evidence that SOME nature-oriented settlements take this attitude. The Adventurer's League scenario Tales Trees Tell revolves around several groups of fae of the Quivering Forest, and how they react to incursions into their home. In this case, though, the fae involved had a pact with the city of Phlan to not enter the forest.

Also see the story of the Halfaxe trail in Cormanthor, near [Harrowdale](http://realmofadventure.wikia.com/wiki/Harrowdale). This was centuries prior to the current FR timeline, but provides another example of isolationist Elven behaviour.